# load files from SFTP in ssis package

Tags: ssis

In ssis package how to download files from SFTP server . FTP details and FileName should read from config file. Rename the files to append timestamp.files are .csv files. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to create ssis package where csv files are in SFTP server, where FTP details and filenames should read from config file. Rename the file to append datetime to it.